# Is there a way in Django to filter through choices?

Tags: python, sql, django, user-interface

There's a field in Django called choices, where you can fill out 'choices'.

'''

```
connector = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        choices = Food,
        verbose_name="food",
        

Food = [
            ('chicken', 'Chicken'),
            ('queso', 'Queso'),
            ('carne', 'Carne')
        ]
```

'''

Like that for example.

But what if the list of choices is much, much larger than just 3? Is there a way to add a searching functionality so that it can narrow it down? Like an autocomplete? I have a list of over 300 items that I want as choices, but I only want them to show when I type the relevant letters - i.e. I type "A" I'd like a dropdown list of the choices that start with A.

Is there a way to do this easily within Django?

Comment: I'm pretty sure choices isn't really designed for what you're trying to do. If you have over 300 items, that means you should create a table (model) for those items, not cram them all into the choices for a single attribute of a different model. Then create a relation via FK, M2M or whatever is applicable between your original model and this new model.

Comment: @m.arthur okay, if I do that, then is there a way to search and filter through that model?

Comment: well for autocomplete behavior you'll need to use jQuery, django can't do that on its own. search for jQuery + django autocomplete tutorials, there are many out there.